# confusion of cassandra super columns and composite columns

Tags: model, cassandra, time-series

In the example of music album from cassandra,

(a)

```
artist    K
id        C
title
album
```

is this a design of super column? The columns are indexed by (id), and (title, album) are stored as sub-columns?

If the model looks like this,

(b)

```
artist    K
id        C
title     C
album
```

then it becomes a composite column design? With the columns indexed by(id|title) and each column just store (album)?

Is my understanding correct? I am design a time series database, with 50 sensors sharing the same timestamp, I am going to put them into a wide row, like

(c)

```
location  K
device    K
year      K
month     K
day       K
timestamp C
sensor1   
sensor2
....
sensor50
```

If I only query sensor1 at give time range, does it mean that cassandra will scan through all 50 sensors consecutively and pick the only one I need?

maybe I should use schema

(d)

```
location   K
device     K
year       K
month      K
day        K
sensorname C
timestamp  C
value
```

what are the differences concerning partition size and reading performance?

Comment: maybe both (a) and (b) are composite columns schema?

Comment: where did you find the example?  super columns should never be used anymore.  it looks like you're trying to build a thrift application, which is effectively deprecated.  Take a look at CQL, it's how you should be building your applications http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_intro_c.html

Comment: The example is from the online tutorial on planet cassandra. It is not code of particular application, but rather a design schema, with K represents partition key and C represent clustering key. I know it is not recommended to use super columns. But I am confused about whether they are exits anymore or not? The documents are very confusing, not specifying CQL version and no clear description of the data orders on disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clustering columns are not super columns, no.

I recommend watching the DataStax Academy videos on data modeling.

https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds201-foundations-apache-cassandra/c-data-model-clustering-columns